# pandas groupby index value

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to groupby an index label (instead of a column label)? This seems like it should be trivial so perhaps I am missing something.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                   ['a', 'a', 'b'], 
                   ['b', 'b', 'c']],
                  index=['q', 'r', 's'], 
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df
    x   y   z
q   a   b   c
r   a   a   b
s   b   b   c
```

This works as I would expect:

```
df.groupby('x', axis=0).agg(sum)

    y   z
x       
a   ba  cb
b   b   c
```

However this fails

```
df.groupby('s', axis=1).agg(sum)
```

With a `KeyError`.

What I would hope to get out is:

```
s   b   c
q   ab  c
r   aa  b
```

Is it possible to groupby an index value? I realize that I can transpose the table, however I need to perform multiple groupbys and it would be much less prone to errors if I could avoid that. Also if the `axis` parameter does not specify the axis to apply the groupby to, what does it do?

Comment: You mean `df.groupby(level='b', axis=1).agg(sum)`?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question as it may not have been clear what I was trying to do.  I do not have a multi-index.

Comment: It's my opinion that transposition is the "correct" approach.  All the groupby options make some assumption about which column's values will be used to group by.  Because you are restricting the answer to not include the use of transposition, don't be surprised if you don't get many answers.  I hope I'm wrong, I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `r` in `df.groupby('r', axis=1).agg(sum)` should be `s`. Maybe it's your mistake??

Anyway,

You can groupby based on index value like below. (My workaround...)

```
print df[~df.index.isin(['s'])].groupby(df.loc['s'], axis=1).agg(sum)

s   b  c
q  ab  c
r  aa  b
```

Comment: You are correct, the example should have been grouping by `s`